# MongoDB find query with parameters loads whole document in memory or not?

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, when we pass field names as the second parameter for find query does mongodb load whole document in memory or only the memory associated with those fields ?

Comment: It only loads required fields. Remember it always return _id by default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the MongoDB server side, the whole document is stored in one place on disk. Because MongoDB use memory mapped files, any document access requires that whole document to be loaded in memory. After the query has run, only the requested fields are transferred to the client. This means that on the client/driver side, only the requested fields are stored in memory, and not the whole document

Comment: ok...so even if we require subset of fields...on server side whole document will be retrieved...and hence increase server load...right ???

Comment: The document isn't "retrieved" as such. It's just stored in a specific place in the data files and found through an index. And I would hardly expect an increase in server load between "some fields" and "all fields", as most documents are < 4kb. The blocks that the OS reads from disk for MongoDB are also 4kb (that's how memory mapped files work)